# How to develop a search plugin to integrate it with joomla's built-in search

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using joomla 2.5.7.
I have to develop a search plugin to integrate it with joomla's built-in search.
The need is to search inside "**Titles**", "**Descriptions**" from a Video List Component.
I am thinking something like joomla's built-in "**Search - Categories**", "**Search - Content**", "**Search - Contacts**" etc.

I have read this... http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin , but I am not sure how much is up to date!

Any suggestions ?!

Thank you!

Comment: You answered your own question. The documentation you liked is current for J2.5.

Answer (score 0):

If someone use this http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin tutorial... 
Change these lines of code...

```
$mainframe->registerEvent( 'onSearch', 'plgSearchnameofplugin' );
$mainframe->registerEvent( 'onSearchAreas', 'plgSearchnameofpluginAreas' );
```

with these...

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->registerEvent( 'onContentSearch', 'plgSearchnameofplugin' );
$mainframe->registerEvent( 'onContentSearchAreas', 'plgSearchnameofpluginAreas' );
```